# How to substract values from all keys in Pair Rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, key-value

I have a `Pair Rdd[(Int, Array[Double])]` and i want for each key to substract all the other arrays from its own.

For example if my `rdd` is:

```
[(1, Array_1[Double])]
[(2, Array_2[Double])]
[(3, Array_3[Double])]
```

I want:

```
[(1, Sum( Array_1[Double] - Array_i[Double] ))],  where i=2,3
[(2, Sum( Array_2[Double] - Array_i[Double] ))],  where i=1,3
[(3, Sum( Array_3[Double] - Array_i[Double] ))],  where i=1,2
```

I thought about transforming the `rdd` to `Rdd[(Int, (Array, List(Array)))]` but i don't know if there could something easier than that.

Any idea for solution?

**The answer is:**

```
 val S = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter{ case(a, b) => a._1!=b._1}
          .map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2-x._2._2)))
          .reduceByKey(_+_).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [cartesian](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations) product of self rdd and then groupbyKey.

e.g.

```
val rdd=sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
rdd.cartesian(rdd).groupByKey().map(.......subtract here....)
```

Comment: Could i do a cartesian with all the others except itself for each id? E.g in id 1, do cartesian with only 2 and 3.

Comment: No that's not possible. You could exclude self id in map operation which is in 2nd line in example.